# Regex match key except one

Tags: python, regex

I have a python list. It contains strings like `items[number].some field`. I want get all this strings except strings that match `items[<number>].classification`. How I can do this by regex or maybe there is another way?

As an example, I have something like:

> data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region
>
> data.items.[0].classification.scheme
>
> data.items.[0].classification.id
>
> data.items.[0].description

And I want to stay only with :

> data.items.[0].description
>
> data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region

Comment: This is a bit more direct but couldn't you just throw away string that contains `'classification'`? By using `str.find` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for a negative lookahead combined with anchors:

```
^((?:.(?!classification))+)$
```

In Python code this would be:

```
import re

string = """
data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region
data.items.[0].classification.scheme
data.items.[0].classification.id
data.items.[0].description
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^((?:.(?!classification))+)$', re.MULTILINE)

matches = rx.findall(string)
print matches
# ['data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region', 'data.items.[0].description']
```

Obviously, this will work with a list as well:

```
import re

lst = ['data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region',
'data.items.[0].classification.scheme',
'data.items.[0].classification.id',
'data.items.[0].description']

# no need for re.MULTILINE here
rx = re.compile(r'^((?:.(?!classification))+)$') 

matches = [x for x in lst if rx.match(x)]
print matches
# ['data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region', 'data.items.[0].description']
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rZ6cM4/1).

Answer (score 2):

To do this, I used this regex to match the strings you want to discard:

```
data.items.\[\d+\].classification
```

Say I have a Python list containing those items called `l`:

```
l = ["data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region",
"data.items.[0].classification.scheme",
"data.items.[0].classification.id",
"data.items.[0].description"]
```

I can then use a list comprehension to only keep the values that don't match the regex, by using `re.match`.

```
>>> import re
>>> [x for x in l if not re.match(r"data.items.\[\d+\].classification", x)]
['data.items.[0].deliveryAddress.region', 'data.items.[0].description']
```